# Why don't makefiles behave more like shell scripts within recipes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I find makefiles very useful, and the header of each recipe

```
<target> : [dependencies]
```

is helpful.  Within a recipe, the prefixes @ and - are useful, as well as the automatically-defined variables like $@ and $?.  However, besides that, I find the way of coding the actual recipe to be strange and unhelpful.  There are so many questions on StackOverflow along the lines of "how to do this in a makefile" for something that's simple (or at least more familiar) to do in bash.

Is there a reason why the recipe contents are not just interpreted as a regular shell script?  Reading the manual pages, there seems to be many tools with equivalent functionality to a shell script but with different syntax.  I end up specifying .ONESHELL and escaping $ with $$, or sometimes just call a script from the recipe when I can't figure out how to make it work in a makefile.  My question is whether this is just unfortunate design, or are there are important features of makefiles that force them to be designed this way?

Comment: Make and bash are both concise languages, but they have fundamentally different designs (e.g. bash is procedural, Make is not). Designing a clean interface between them that doesn't hobble either one is very difficult.

Comment: The power of make is not in the scripting (which I agree is obtuse) but in the way it handles dependencies and parallism. Make can call make on itself or on other makefiles allowing for very large projects in any language to be compiled efficiently.  If you think of make as a recipe generator that you can embed some lines of shell script (any shell btw) then you are getting there.  .ONESHELL breaks one of the ways it can parallel tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how to answer your question.  Probably that means it's not really appropriate for StackOverflow.

The requirement for using `$$` instead of `$` is obvious.  The reasoning for using a separate shell for each logical line of a makefile instead of passing the entire recipe to a single shell, is less clear.  It could have worked either way, and this is the way it was chosen.

There is one advantage to the way it works now, although maybe most people don't care about it: you only have to indent the first recipe line with TAB, if you use backslash newline to continue each line.  If you *don't* use backslash newline, then every line has to be indented with TAB else you don't know where the recipe ends.

If your question is, could Stuart Feldman have made very different syntax decisions that would have made it easier to write long/complex recipes in makefiles, then sure.  Choosing a more obscure character than `$` as a variable introducer would reduce the amount of escaping (although, shell scripting uses pretty much every special character somewhere so "reduce" is the best you can do).  Choosing an explicit "start/stop" character sequence for recipes would make it simpler to write long recipes, possibly at the expense of some readability.

But that's not how it was done.